# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I created angular(6) project with angular -cli from scratch. 
Created library as said in [the official wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library)

And got an error when tried to import my new library. 
I'm been checking configuration for 2 days.

`ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:./lib/tvmaze.component' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:./lib/tvmaze.module' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:./lib/tvmaze.service' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:./public_api' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:./tvmaze.component' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjs-proxy:@angular/core' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5/tvmaze.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'commonjsHelpers' in '/Users/alexanderkozhevin/Desktop/lib-demo/node_modules/tvmazerrr/fesm5'`

Comment: Maybe you forgot commonjs-proxy in the package.json of your library?

Comment: No, it's was package error. @Powkachu

Comment: @AlexanderKozhevin Please tell us that steps you took to resolve this error in your package.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've seen is that in tsconfig.lib.json of the library that is being built the module should be set as follows:

```
"module": "es2015"
```

Not setting this or setting it to something higher can cause problems such as the ones seen above.
See also this git entry:

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/944